# How to detect Volume Button Press (+/-) in iOS after volume has reached maximum or minimum?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, mpvolumeview

I am trying to detect when a user presses the volume up/down button on an iOS device. I am not trying to change the system volume in my application, but instead the volume of a speaker that the user is connected to, so I don't need to modify the system volume (which I understand we are not supposed to do post iOS 11.4).

The current notification in AVSession only fires when there is a change in the volume and not every time the user hits one of those two buttons, so the notification does not fire when the volume is maxed out and the user hits the volume up button.

Comment: If you are trying to send messages to some other device (speaker), how are you doing that if changing the ios system volume doesn't do it?

Comment: I have access to the speakers SDK.